# Dynamic Vhost Config - Apache v2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

This configuration was working on Apache version 2.3 however, when I updated to Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) PHP/7.2.11 its not longer working. Only the first and second directives are, but the third isn't, its only showing index of the root of the folder, when its supposed to add the folder in the DEFINE as defined. Has anything changed in Apache/2.4.34, can't find any thing to resolve the issue or maybe am missing something.

PS. I have checked other Q&A the had a similar issue but none of the solutions worked.

This question is different due to the following:

1. Its addressing dynamic vitual host and not static
2. This is using apache version 2.4 not 2.2 as the indicated answer is.
3. The entire configuration of this vhost file is different to the indicated answer

Thanks

```
Define USER currentUser
Define PATH "/Users/${USER}/Sites"
Define CRAFT2 public
Define CRAFT3 web

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot ${PATH}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.dv
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot ${PATH}/%1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.dv
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot ${PATH}/%1/${CRAFT3}
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your virtual hosts are missing the `ServerName` directive. Without it, `ServerAlias` is ignored.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, Adding the ServerName does not solve the issue either and this same config was working without the ServerName in version 2.2 but not in version 2.4

Comment: Then please edit your question to show your actual virtual hosts, because it shows your virtual hosts do not have `ServerName`.

Comment: But the point of my question is that, this exact configuration worked in version 2.2, _without the ServerName_, and not in 2.4 so adding the ServerName would not have made any difference.

Comment: Yes, it did work in 2.2 without `ServerName`. But 2.4 is not 2.2. It doesn't work that way anymore. You must have a `ServerName` now.

Comment: I've added the ServerName and its still not working. Only the first directive is loading and second isn't. And it was doing the same-thing without the ServerName as well so its kinda of an odd one.  Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Well, leave it in, because it does need to be there. Edit your question to show your existing config, and we'll go from there.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen based on your comments, @Said. But please do include the current config with the correct Servername directives as Michael Hampton recommended; it'll make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @JennyD, thanks for voting to reopen, appreciate it. Based on the different configuration changes made/tried so far, don't see the ServerName as being the issue, because even when I added the ServerName, same results. Still looking, since the key issue in that the above configuration's first directive is being read and run, but not the subsequent ones. Will update when a solution is found.